# Unit testing LitElement

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, web-component, lit-element, polymer-3.x

I have been looking everywhere and can't seem to find an answer so while this question may not contain a lot of code I was hoping that there was someone here with experience in subcomponents / Lit framework that could tell me how to unit test the components that you make.

Right now, I have the following element.

```
class SdkArticle extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            data: {type: Object}
        };
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.data = {};
    }

    render() {
        return html `
        <style>
            .row {
              display: flex;
            }
            
            /* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
            .column {
              flex: ${100 / this.data.columnData.length}%;
              padding: 10px;
              height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
            }
            h2{
            padding-left:  10px;
            }
        </style>
       
        <div>
          <h2>${this.data.title}</h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
             ${this.data.columnData.map(
            columData =>
                html`
                    ${this.generateHtml(columData)}
                `,
        )}
         </div>
`;
    }

    //Based on the settings we generate the extra html depending on the columns
    generateHtml(columnData) {
        switch (columnData.dataType) {
            case 'image':
                if (columnData.addon != null) {
                    if (columnData.addon !== null && columnData.addon.type === 'link') {
                        return html `<div class="column"><img src=${columnData.imageSrc}></div><div><sdk-button link=${columnData.addon.href}>${columnData.addon.text}</sdk-button></div>`;
                    }
                    else {
                        return html `<div class="column"><img src=${columnData.imageSrc}></div>`;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return html `<div class="column"><img src=${columnData.imageSrc}></div>`;
                }
            case 'text':
                if (columnData.addon != null && columnData.addon.type === 'link') {
                    return html `<div class="column"><p>${columnData.text} </p><sdk-button link=${columnData.addon.href}>${columnData.addon.text}</sdk-button> </div>`;
                } else {

                    return html `<div class="column"><p>${columnData.text} </p> </div>`;
                }
        }
    }
}

customElements.define('sdk-article', SdkArticle);
```

What framework do I use to test this? And how can I write a test to test my component?

Comment: Is this polymer3? If so, could you add a tag for that?

Comment: @Cat yes it is ive added the tag

Comment: Here's the documentation for that https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/tests You can test either via the polymer-cli or in the browser (with a url like `localhost:8080/components/my-cool-component/test/my-cool-component_test.html`) You could probably also use another testing tool like Jest or Mocha, but why bother when polymer has one baked in?